# How many verses are there in the Mukhya Upanishads?

Tags: upanishads

Wikipedia says the following 13 Upanishads are the Mukhya Upanishads:

- Isha Upanishad
- Kena Upanishad
- Kaṭha Upanishad
- Praṣna Upanishad
- Muṇḍaka Upanishad
- Māṇḍūkya Upanishad
- Taittirīya Upanishad
- Aitareya Upanishad
- Chāndogya Upanishad
- Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upanishad
- Shvetashvatara Upanishad
- Kaushitaki Upanishad
- Maitri Upanishad

My question is, how many verses are there in all the Mukhya Upanishads in total?

Comment: All of them are available to read at [Sanskritdocuments](https://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskrit/upanishhat/). So, one can visit each and then count no. of verse and then add/sum all.

Comment: This is basically a counting problem or something else is there in it?

Comment: Is there any special reason for asking number of verses in all Mukhya Upanishads?

Answer (score 3):

- Isha Upanishad - 18 verses
- Kena Upanishad - 35 verses
- Kaṭha Upanishad - 119 verses
- Praṣna Upanishad - 67 verses
- Muṇḍaka Upanishad - 65 verses
- Māṇḍūkya Upanishad - 12 verses
- Taittirīya Upanishad - 30 verses
- Aitareya Upanishad - 33 verses
- Chāndogya Upanishad - 627 verses
- Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upanishad - 434 verses
- Shvetashvatara Upanishad - 113 verses
- Kaushitaki Upanishad - 50 verses
- Maitri Upanishad - 73 verses

In total, we have 1676 verses in all the 13 Upanishads.